# Tools to bound the singular values of a finite sum of random matrices from below?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, random-matrices, measure-concentration

[Matrix Chernoff bounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_Chernoff_bound) (see also [this arXiv paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4389)) are usually used to give upper bounds on the largest eigenvalue of a finite sum of random matrices. Sometimes it can also be used to give a lower bound on the smallest eigenvalue of a finite sum of random *positive semidefinite* (PSD) matrices.

For PSD matrices, the eigenvalues are the same as the singular values. My question is:

> Is there any tool, or any other special cases (apart from the PSD case) for which there is a tool, to obtain lower bounds on the singular values of a finite sum of random matrices, or random symmetrical matrices?